# iOS image from context cannot release

Tags: ios, memory, cgcontext, iphone-6-plus

Now I am working with a chat view, the cell in the table view is a cell with async layer. The async layer is mostly like `Facebook's _ASDisplayLayer`. When I received `lot of message`, the `memory increased crazily` on Plus device. But it is fine on iPhone.Then I used instrument to find out why the memory not released. I found that the image create from `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` cannot be released. I googled this problem but nothing useful.

Have anyone suffered this problem as me? Why this happened?
What if the different of `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` between `iPhone` and `Plus`?

Comment: What happens if you wrap the `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` and everything you do with it until you set the image to nil, in an `@autoreleasepool`

Comment: @autoreleasepool wrapped has nothing to do with this problem.